# Generate PDF in Lambda and Store it in S3

Tags: java, file, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using PDF Generator to generate PDF and then am storing it in Lambda local storage first using
`pdDocument.save(local storage path)`.
Then am using
`s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file))` to upload file to S3.
Everything is working fine but when i try to remove local storage logic and use ByteOutputStream :

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pdDocument.save(byteArrayOutputStream);


    String content = byteArrayOutputStream.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

    byte[] contentAsBytes = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentAsBytes);
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.setContentType(contentType);
    objectMetadata.setContentLength(content.length());
    objectMetadata.setContentEncoding(UTF_8);
    s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, input, objectMetadata));
```

Generate PDF is giving `Failed to load PDF document` error.

Not able to understand where am I going wrong.
Is there another way to upload file to S3 without using Lambda local storage?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was i was converting content to string,, converting to byte array generated report correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).